# File access okay in debug but not in executable in VB.net

Tags: vb.net

I my code I use streamwriter to open/create a file and write to it.  This works fine in debug mode but I get a "permission denied" error when running the executable.  Here's the code in question below.

```
      Left out part of the code in first post, here's the correct snippet:

        Dim DateOfTest As Date
        Dim TesterName As String
        Dim SerialNumber As String

        TesterName = TextBoxTester.Text
        DateOfTest = Now
        SerialNumber = TextBoxBoardSN.Text

        'File writing for test info
        Dim path As String = "C:\" & SerialNumber & ".txt"

        If File.Exists(path) Then
            File.Delete(path)
        End If

        ' Create the file. 
        Dim writer As StreamWriter = New StreamWriter(path)

        writer.WriteLine("CPX Loopback Test " & vbCrLf)
        writer.WriteLine("Serial Number " & vbTab & "Tester Name" & vbTab & "Date")
        writer.WriteLine(SerialNumber & vbTab & vbTab & TesterName & vbTab & vbTab & DateOfTest & vbCrLf)
```

Comment: Have you solved it out?

Answer (score 3):

Try: Right Click => Run as Administrator

If that solved the problem, it was due to privileges of visual studio being greater than those for the .exe